# SQL Query to show count of same results

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT Score FROM (
SELECT SUM(Score) AS Score
FROM ResponseData
WHERE ScoreGUID='baf5dd3e-949c-4255-ad48-fd8f2485399f'
GROUP BY Section
) AS Totals
GROUP BY Score
```

And it produces this:

```
Score
0
1
2
2
4
5
5
```

But, what I really want is the number of each of the scores, like this:

```
Score   Count
0       1
1       1
2       2
4       1
5       2
```

I want to show how many of each score, One 0, One 1, Two 2's, One 4, and 2 5's.

But I am not sure how to do this query, would someone be able to show me how to achieve this?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
SELECT Score,count(score) as cnt 
FROM ResponseData
WHERE ScoreGUID='baf5dd3e-949c-4255-ad48-fd8f2485399f'
GROUP BY Score
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I actually just found that, by you verified and reinforced what I did, thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Definitely, I need to what 4 minutes, LOL!!!  Also, I have a second part to the question, but I will post a new one!!

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
SELECT Score, COUNT(Score)
FROM ResponseData
WHERE ScoreGUID='baf5dd3e-949c-4255-ad48-fd8f2485399f'
GROUP BY Score
```

should work. But I don't understand the meaning of your:

```
group by Section
```

Answer (score 1):

try the follwoing:

```
SELECT Score,count(*) as Count FROM (
SELECT distinct SUM(Score) AS Score
FROM ResponseData
WHERE ScoreGUID='baf5dd3e-949c-4255-ad48-fd8f2485399f'
GROUP BY Section
) AS Totals
GROUP BY Score
```